# Fetch email thread from a table with recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table `emails`:

```
     id     message_id          in_reply_to
      1     <me123@gmail.com>   null
      2     <me345@gmail.com>   <me123@gmail.com>
      3     <me567@gmail.com>   <me345@gmail.com>
      4     <me768@gmail.com>   <me567@gmail.com>
      5     <me910@gmail.com>   null
      6     <me911@gmail.com>   <me768@gmail.com>
      7     <me912@gmail.com>   <me567@gmail.com>
      8     <me913@gmail.com>   <me912@gmail.com>
      9     <me914@gmail.com>   <me913@gmail.com>
      10    <me915@gmail.com>   <me914@gmail.com>
      11    <me916@gmail.com>   <me914@gmail.com>
     ...
```

(this table holds the thread of emails, we need to fetch the email thread)

1. I just know the `message_id` and `id` of an email and its `in_reply_to` can be null or not null.
2. I need to fetch all the `message_id`s and `id`s of those messages where in_reply_to is equal to the `message_id` we know and keep fetching with in_reply_to.
3. Once the message_id is fetched I need to search for other emails who have `in_reply_to` field as this `message_id` and fetch until the coming message_id is not `in_reply_to` of any other messages.
4. There is NO `foreign_key` relationship with respect to `in_reply_to`
   and it's just a list like any other column.
5. `id` is primary-key for emails table, `message_id` is always unique to each email.
6. One `message_id` can be `in_reply_to` of many messages .

If I pass `message_id` = `<me912@gmail.com>`

my output table should be

```
      id     message_id          in_reply_to      
      8     <me913@gmail.com>   <me912@gmail.com>
      9     <me914@gmail.com>   <me913@gmail.com>
      10    <me915@gmail.com>   <me914@gmail.com>
      11    <me916@gmail.com>   <me914@gmail.com>
```

I just know I need to use recursive and I got stuck understanding `WITH RECURSIVE` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

I tried somewhat this:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE emails AS (
    SELECT message_id, in_reply_to FROM emails WHERE id = ?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT message_id, in_reply_to
     FROM emails where in_reply_to =  // Stuck here
   )
   SELECT * 
   FROM emails;
```

Can you help me to fix the query, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the CTE comparing `email_id` and `in_reply_to`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
thread
AS
(
SELECT e.id,
       e.message_id,
       e.in_reply_to
       FROM emails e
       WHERE id = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT e.id,
       e.message_id,
       e.in_reply_to
       FROM emails e
            INNER JOIN thread t
                       ON t.message_id = e.in_reply_to
)
SELECT *
       FROM thread
       ORDER BY id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=df121264e0e8978a87e7e5845bbef470)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Explaination would have been helpful. But it's fine :thumbsup